# Running multiple websites using ASP.NET membership in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis-7, asp.net-membership

I have been doing Google searches trying to find a resolution to this issue, but either there isn't one or I have not touched on the right search string to give me an answer.

I have multiple websites defined under the default website (inherited it this way) running on Server 2008 R2.  I access these externally by ip-address/site1 ip-address/site2 etc.  Each site uses a login and password.  All sites point to the same database which has the standard ASP.NET membership implemented.

I have set the application name property in the web.config files.  I have unique application IDs defined in the database for each application.  Originally everything was set to "/" so I changed it to be unique.

The main issue that I am having is that when I am using IE and I log into one site it kicks me out of the other site if I have it open in a separate tab.  Is there any way to stop this from happening.

The authentication from the web config file is:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" path="/" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" timeout="1440" />
    </authentication>`

Comment: Do you get the same result when running each IE window InPrivate mode?

Comment: Good thought, but if both sites are open in separate windows things work just fine. The problem is when bots sites are open in the same window but different tabs.

Comment: Could you post the setting of `<authentication>` inside web.config?

Comment: Added the authentication to the question above.